# parameters as part of url instead of after question mark

Tags: php, url, web

I want to know if we can achieve something like this:
`example.com/apps?id='blahblah'` converted to `example.com/apps/id/blahblah` ie. parameters becoming pages themselves. I want to create seperate urls for each id but dynamically. Is this possible in php or any other workaround.

Comment: What you are looking for is called [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/)

Comment: Can't understand why people have downvoted. Is it necessary that i will know about mod_rewrite. It is knowledge based and not IQ based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .htaccess to achieve this.

.htaccess basically rewrites the url to your original location. So to do what you asked in your question it would be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule apps/id/(.*?)$ apps?id=$1
```

Comment: i have put the same and trying with localhost/xyz/apps/id/123, but it does not redirect to localhost/xyz/apps?id=123. Can you point out my mistake.

Comment: It will not redirect, it will rewrite (show same page in different url). Secondly, You are using xyz sub directory. So have you placed this .htaccess in the xyz directory?

Comment: yes i have placed this in xyz directory. so according to you, if we type localhost/xyz/apps/id/123, it will rewrite to localhost/xyz/apps?id=123 and hit the index.php file in apps directory, right? But that is not happening.

Comment: It will not hit index.php, it will goto 'apps'. If you want index.php then use index.php?id=$1 (Also before rewriting first open the original url in your browser to verify it is working. In this case http://localhost/xyz/apps?id=123)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting downvoted because "mod rewrite in php" has been widely documented with tutorials and articles. Try to search for it here or on Google and you will find plenty of results.

Anyway, if you can't or won't use Apache's `mod_rewrite`, you can do the same in pure PHP by parsing the HTTP request and process accordingly.

For example

```
$request_path = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$request_path = explode("/", $request_path);

// example.com/apps.php/id/blahblah
// $request_path[0] => "example.com"
// $request_path[1] => "apps.php"
// $request_path[2] => "id"
// $request_path[3] => "blahblah"
```

*Notice I added `.php` extension to `apps`. If you wish to hide the `.php` extension you must use `mod_rewrite` anyway.*

From here on you can use the `$request_path` to figure out what the request wants.